# How to prevent user from edit someone's else post

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Let's say I have `User` model and `Post` model. `Post` model contains field `user_id`.
`User` has `$hasMany` on `Post` and `Post` has `$belongsTo` on `User`.

I have some post edit action:

```
PostsController::edit($id) {
    if($this->request->isPost())
    {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        $this->Post->save();
    }

    $post = $this->Post->read($id);
    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

I use `AuthComponent` to login users.

How can I prevent user from editing some1 else post? Is there any cake build in function/option to do this? Because some1 can login and post edit action with any id. It's not even case of saving the post data - let's say post is private (only owner should see it) - when someone will call posts/edit/some_id it will see the edit form of this post...

The easier way is to just add this at the beginning of edit action:

```
$this->Post->id = $id;
if($this->Post->readField('user_id') != $this->Auth->user('id')) 
{ //trigger error or redirect }
```

But I would have to add this at the beginning of each action that updates/reads any data that belongs to some user. So I am looking for more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no way of avoiding adding a line to check if a user is authorized to perform an action. Even if you use ACL (Access Control Lists), which is one of Cake's most powerful features.

But as you speak of elegance in general, ACLs will be beauty at its best :) Careful though, they've got a steep learning curve. Don't give up easy, its well worth it.

You should see ACLs from the Book http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

Comment: Actually, there is a way of avoiding adding a line, this could probably be solved by comparing user IDs for edit action in a single place, such as `AppController::isAuthorized()` or `beforeFilter()`.

Answer (score 3):

Well an exact example ( handily using a Post/User model too ) is available in the [cake manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what)

Everyones a winner!